# Create New Interface, Security Levels?

Tags: networking, 18.04, security, interface

I've just brought up a new virtualized Ubuntu machine (image file: ubuntu-18.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.img) and when it spun up, it automatically created an interface that connected to the host:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ifconfig
ens3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.0.2.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::f6a7:39ff:fe24:6fd3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f4:a7:39:24:6f:d3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 816060  bytes 59441737 (59.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 39912  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 775552  bytes 66017744 (66.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

root@ubuntu:~#
```

The IPv4 and MAC addresses were assigned by the host, and I can SSH into the Ubuntu VM just fine with the 192.0.2.100 IP address.  The interface works just great.

So far, so good.  But I have a need to create two other interfaces, so I did so using "ifconfig":

```
root@ubuntu:~# ifconfig ens4 10.0.0.10/24
root@ubuntu:~# ifconfig ens5 10.10.10.200/24
root@ubuntu:~#
root@ubuntu:~# ifconfig
ens3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.0.2.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::f6a7:39ff:fe24:6fd3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f4:a7:39:24:6f:d3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        ...etc...

ens4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::f6a7:39ff:fe24:6fd2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f4:a7:39:24:6f:d2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        ...etc...

ens5: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.10.10.200  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.71.255
        inet6 fe80::f6a7:39ff:fe24:6fda  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f4:a7:39:24:6f:da  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        ...etc...

root@ubuntu:~#
```

Note that the new interfaces MUST use these assigned IPs, I can't rely on DHCP for addresses.

I note that from other servers on the 10.10.10.x network, I can ping the Ubuntu VM on 10.10.10.200.  So Network Layer 3 is working.

Here's the problem...  While I can ping 10.10.10.200, I can't SSH, FTP, netcat, or do anything TCP to the same IP address.  Attempted connections time out.  When I tcpdump on Ubuntu, I can see the beginnings of the TCP handshake, but it looks like the connection is never established:

```
root@ubuntu:~# tcpdump -i ens5
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ens5, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
19:08:05.171265 IP 10.10.10.10.46988 > ubuntu.ssh: Flags [S], seq 4112466036, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2621364955 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
19:08:05.171295 IP ubuntu.ssh > 10.10.10.10.46988: Flags [S.], seq 2729080149, ack 4112466037, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3132539741 ecr 2621364955,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:08:06.171804 IP 10.10.10.10.46988 > ubuntu.ssh: Flags [S], seq 4112466036, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2621365956 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
19:08:06.171824 IP ubuntu.ssh > 10.10.10.10.46988: Flags [S.], seq 2729080149, ack 4112466037, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3132540741 ecr 2621364955,nop,wscale 7], length 0
^C
root@ubuntu:~#
```

At this point, I'm assuming the problem lies in how I created the new ens4 and ens5 interfaces; I just used the "ipconfig" command with a minimum of options:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ifconfig ens4 10.0.0.10/24
root@ubuntu:~# ifconfig ens5 10.10.10.200/24
```

I know that in RedHat, interfaces are assigned security levels or zones or something and if you want to get all traffic through the interface, you have to make sure those settings are correct.  But I can't seem to find any similar information in the Ubuntu world.

So...  Am I taking a too-simplistic approach to creating these interfaces?  Is there a better way?  Or are my woes caused by something else?

Many thanks!

Comment: Security Levels in RHEL trace to firewall policies, you would need to set up firewall rules for traffic restrictions if you intended to do that.  Have you considered setting static IPs with Netplan for those interfaces?  You will also need to pick the ‘default’ interface as well in routing rules to make that work right as well.

Comment: @ThomasWard  Thanks Thomas!  I currently have the Ubuntu's ufw disabled, under the theory that if the firewall is shut off, traffic will flow freely.  No luck, however.  Are you saying that I'd need to enable ufw and basically do a "PERMIT ALL" firewall rule?

Comment: by 'flow freely' what do you mean?  Flowing via subnets properly?  Is this box acting as a router?  That won't happen unless you configure NAT rules properly at the `iptables` level not the UFW level.  Which you'd have to do in RHEL as well, but its 'security levels' is probably a SPECIALIZED RHEL build to take the place of a router and automatically handle the NAT rules.

Comment: @ThomasWard Good question.  This Ubuntu is intended to be an end host, specifically an IPFIX collector.  All it has to do is receive incoming IPFIX data records and SSH management traffic.  What is driving me nuts is that currently the Ubuntu VM accepts ICMP packets, but no TCP or UDP traffic.  I set up an "ACCEPT ANY ANY" firewall rule in ufw but that didn't have any effect.  I do see iptables is running and has a lot of rules permitting ICMP, which makes me think you're on to something here.  I don't know much about how ufw and iptables work together, but I assume I'll need to config both?

Comment: You would have to configure one or the other.  I am currently not near a computer or I would pull you into chat to discuss what you need to achieve.

Comment: @ThomasWard Thanks boss.  When might be a good time to sync up?  And what chat program do you favor?  (I'm largely unavailable over the weekend, unfortunately.)

Comment: I meant the Ask Ubuntu / Stack Exchange chat system ;)

Comment: @ThomasWard  Ah.  I'll have to learn how to use it, then.  :)